# git tf autosquash exception

Tags: tfs, git-tf

I am trying to push a git repository to tfs and it has multiple branches on it. I get a stackoverflow error with the deep checkin. Looks like a recrusive call fail. Is there a workaround?

git tf checkin --deep –autosquash

Fails at com.microsoft.gittf.core.util.CommitWalker.detectAutoSquashedPath(CommitWalker.java:260)

Comment: How many commits, roughly, are in this repository?  "Auto squash" in a very large repo could consume a significant amount of memory.

Comment: Around 9000 commits are there.

Comment: A workaround for this may be available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075221/git-tf-checkin-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-stackoverflowerror